# asignar un icono a un qfile

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy intentando asignar un icono a un qfile. Cuando me refiero a un qfile me refiero al qfile de toda la vida:

```
QFile file("example.txt");
```

Documentación:

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html

Pero lo que quería era asignarle a este qfile un icono. El problema no encuentro documentación al respecto aunque leyendo sobre qfileprovider pero no encontre ninguno ejemplo ni algun método practico para poder cambiarle el icono a un qfile. Mi pregunta cual es el método posible o algun ejemplo para llevarlo a la práctica ya que apenas encuentro ejemplos.

Comment: la clase QFile provee una interfaz para leer y escribir sobre archivos, no es una interfaz gráfica por lo que no podrás añadirle un ícono, explicate más en lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Los ficheros no llevan un icono asociado *per se*, salvo que sean ejecutables y no siempre (depende de si el SO soporta esta característica o no).

Para asociar un icono a una extensión determinada es necesario configurarlo a nivel del sistema operativo. De esta forma al abrir cualquier explorador de ficheros la extensión elegida se mostrará con el icono que hemos indicado.

¿Cómo se realiza esta configuración? Depende del SO, detalle que no indicas.

**Windows**

Hay dos formas de asociar iconos. Todo dependerá de si el fichero está asociado a un programa determinado o no. La documentación al respecto la puedes encontrar en [este enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427(v=vs.85).aspx). Yo te explico la forma sencilla:

Hay que crear la siguiente entrada:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.[EXTENSION]

Y en dicha entrada creamos una entrada con nombre `DefaultIcon`. En esta segunda entrada modificamos el registro `(Default)` para que su valor sea se corresponda con la ruta del icono:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  .AAA
    DefaultIcon
     (Default) = [PATH_DEL_FICHERO]
```

Finalmente, si deseamos que los cambios se apliquen instantáneamente hay que llamar a `SHChangeNotify()`.

**Linux**

[Enlace original de esta sección](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux)

Puedes usar xdg-utils de [freedesktop.org Portland](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/).

Registro del icono para un tipo MIME:

```
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 48 myicon-file-type.png x-application-mytype
```

Crear el fichero de configuración:
Create a configuration file ([freedesktop Shared MIME documentation](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="application/x-mytype">  
   <comment>A witty comment</comment>
   <comment xml:lang="it">Uno Commento</comment>
   <glob pattern="*.myapp"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

Instalación del fichero de configuración:

```
xdg-mime install mytype-mime.xml
```

Estos pasos permiten asociar un icono a un formato determinado. Puedes usar [`xdg-mime default`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-mime.html) para asociar una aplicación al tipo MIME después de instalar el fichero [`.desktop`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-desktop-menu.html)

Comment: voy a hacer una pregunta parecida pero más documentada sobre lo que intento

Comment: Tú respuesta sería si el quiere agregar un ícono a un archivo, no a un QFile que es una clase de Qt que gestiona la lectura y escritura de archivos.

Comment: @eferion, a ambos, ya que debiste colocar o preguntar más si tenias dudas sobre la pregunta

Comment: @eferion debiste ayudar a mejorar la pregunta con comentarios, como trate de hacerlo, para eso sirven los comentarios